# What can I do with code analysis upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am upgrading a **big** solution from [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) to [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012). All is done, but the code analysis module was changed in Visual Studio 2012 so I got thousands of CODE analysis errors (many CA1703, CA1709, etc.) What can I do?

It is very hard to manage every manually.

Comment: Start at the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not errors. They are just warnings.

**You can just turn off code analysis**

[How to: Enable and Disable Automatic Code Analysis for Managed Code at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx)

**or reconfigure Code Analysis**

[How to: Configure Code Analysis for a Managed Code Project at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264931.aspx)

VS2012 is not so diffrent that you may think. It's just diffrently configured by default.

Comment: It seams the only way. It will be good if VS can automatically suppressed all this errors and add justification "VS 2012 Upgrade". To fix them manually in future gradually.  But now some errors on global scope code analyzer cannot suppress at all(  It says something like "cannot suppress" when i trying...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a perfect answer for that but the code analysis in VS2012 is much better than in VS2010. There are many improvements in VS2012 and I believe there isn't any one shot solution to this problem. You may have to look into every error case by case.